# Sum of Discrete Random Variables

Tags: random-variable

If I have two independent discrete random variables, say,
$$ X \in \{1,3,10,20\} $$
and
$$ Y \in \{2,3,5,9,11,15\} $$
and let $$Z = X + Y $$
be the sum of two variables. Also, each value taken by either random variable is not equally likely. How do I calculate the distribution of $Z$? More importantly, what does it mean to sum two random variables?

Comment: It rather depends on whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent and whether the values are equally likely.  If so, you could imagine having two fair dice, [one with four sides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-sided_die) and the $X$ values and the other with six sides and the $Y$ values; throw the dice and add the two values together to get the sum $Z$

Comment: Assuming independent and not equally likely what will be the answer?

Comment: Much the same, except now the dice are biased towards particular values